# apt upgrade and locally rebuilt packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I've rebuilt local `qemu` package with some patched applied before build.
As a result I've got about dozen of packages which were installed using:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i $(ls -1 *.deb | grep -v ^qemu-user-static)
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken -y
...
Setting up qemu-system-x86 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42) ...
Setting up qemu-user (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42) ...
...
```

What's interesting if I will run `apt-get upgrade` just after that, some of the packages will be proposed for upgrade from repositories (local and repository package version match), but others are not):

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  qemu-system-arm qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-sparc qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
...
$ apt-cache policy qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-x86:
  Installed: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42
  Candidate: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42
  Version table:
     1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
...
$ apt-cache policy qemu-user
qemu-user:
  Installed: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42
  Candidate: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
...
```

So, it's unclear how dpkg/apt decides which local packages to overwrite and which are not. Is there any criteria I could check on my own?

Comment: Apt/dpkg decides using the version number. Higher version supersedes lower. 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.42 supersedes 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10

Comment: Yeah. That's true for comparing version of xenial and xenial-updates repos. But please take a look at xenial-updates vs /var/lib/dpkg/status. For both packages versions seems to be are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, what's the question about that?

Comment: `qemu-system-x86` is scheduled for upgrade (policy entries differ between remote and local packages, versions are the same), `qemu-user` is NOT scheduled for upgrade (policy entries match between remote and local packages, version are the same).
The questions is why apt behavior differs for those packages.